# How to change the label text every 3 seconds using a timer VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, timer, boolean

```
Dim arr() As String = {"Cake", "Mouse", "Heat", "Tent", "Boots", "Pen", "Stairs", "Cube", "Lion", "Cookies", "Ruler", "Ink"}
Dim timing As Boolean = True
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim n As Integer = 3000
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Timer1.Start()
    For i = 0 To 11
        While timing = True
            If Timer1.Interval = n Then
                Lbl_Word.Text = arr(i)
                timing = False
            End If
        End While
        timing = True
    Next
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

The text of the label isn't changing and i'm not sure what I've done wrong. Please help.

Comment: What is `Timer1`? You should use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and it's `Tick` event to update the UI.

Comment: Thats not how Timers work and you should set `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a forms timer then the code to update the label must be in the .Tick event.  The code below uses a static variable in the event handler to track which string to show.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 3000
    If Not Timer1.Enabled Then 'already running?
        Timer1.Start() 'no
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim arr() As String = {"Cake", "Mouse", "Heat", "Tent", "Boots", "Pen", "Stairs", "Cube", "Lion", "Cookies", "Ruler", "Ink"}
    'Dim arr() As String = {"Cake", "Mouse", "Heat"} 'to test
    Static idx As Integer = 0 'which index in arr
    If idx < arr.Length Then 'more to show?
        'yes
        Lbl_Word.Text = arr(idx)
        idx += 1
    Else
        'no
        Timer1.Stop()
        idx = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

An alternative approach without using a timer.

```
Private TmrTask As task
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TmrTask Is Nothing OrElse TmrTask.IsCompleted Then
        TmrTask = Task.Run(Sub() MyTimerTask())
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyTimerTask()
    Dim arr() As String = {"Cake", "Mouse", "Heat", "Tent", "Boots", "Pen", "Stairs", "Cube", "Lion", "Cookies", "Ruler", "Ink"}
    'Dim arr() As String = {"Cake", "Mouse", "Heat"} 'to test
    For Each s As String In arr
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                           Lbl_Word.Text = s
                       End Sub)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the code inside the Timer events. not in the Button Click event.
and in the Button click event just enable the timer.

Answer (score 0):

-Add a timer

- Make the interval 3000
- On the timer event change the label background color to the color you want you can use from RGB or use random numbers